# How to await two requests with Promise.all then invoke other functions in callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to wait for two requests I get data from firebase DB and set into a state,

I want after two requests Done, concatenate result data in one array,

So I tried to push two requests in an array then use

```
> Promise.all(promises).then(()=>this.updateData());
```

but it does not work as expected, I can see in the console `updateData()` invoked before "
Code here

```
 fetchOrders = async () => {
         ....
 let promises = [];
    promises.push(
      //  First service orders
      database()
        .ref(
          `Providers/CategoriesOrders/${this.state.serviceName[0] ||
            this.state.serviceStorage[0]}`,
        )
        .on('value', this.ordersCallbackOne),
    );



promises.push(
      // Second service orders
      database()
        .ref(
          `Providers/CategoriesOrders/${this.state.serviceName[1] ||
            this.state.serviceStorage[1]}`,
        )
        .on('value', this.ordersCallbackTwo),
    );

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => this.updateData());
  };



ordersCallbackTwo = snapshot => {
    let orderArr = [];
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      orderArr.push({
        snapshotKey: childSnapshot.key,
        username: childSnapshot.val().username,
      });
    });
    this.setState({orderServiceTwo: orderArr}, () =>
      console.log('2', this.state.orderServiceTwo), // it's log data here
    );
  };
```

the function I want to invoke after two requests Done.

```
  updateData = () => {
    // if (this.rejectedOrders?.length >= 1) {
    //   const orders = this.state.orders.filter(
    //     order => !this.rejectedOrders.some(key => order.snapshotKey === key),
    //   );
    //   this.setState({orders, loading: false});
    //   return;
    // }

    console.log('ordersOne!', this.state.orderServiceOne); // empty!

    const order1IDs = new Set(
      this.state.orderServiceOne.map(({snapshotKey}) => snapshotKey),
    );
    console.log('order1IDs', order1IDs);
    const combined = [
      ...this.state.orderServiceOne,
      ...this.orderServiceTwo?.filter(
        ({snapshotKey}) => !order1IDs.has(snapshotKey),
      ),
    ];
    console.log('combined', combined);
    this.setState({
      orders: combined,
      loading: false,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Does this ``database()
        .ref(
          `Providers/CategoriesOrders/${this.state.serviceName[0] ||
            this.state.serviceStorage[0]}`,
        )
        .on('value', this.ordersCallbackOne)`` return a promise?

Comment: @ZHANGLuyao I think yes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on('value')` doesn't return a promise and won't work here.  It's only used to attach a listener to a query, and will receive results indefinitely until call `off()`.

Instead, you should use [once('value')](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#once), which executes the query a single time and returns a promise when it completes.

Comment: UH, I think on('value') works like once, i rewrite it but the `combined` value did not log anything like previously!